# XSL seems not to work when sending XML to WebSite bei RESTful WebService. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, xml, maven, xslt

I'm currently programming a WebService to get food from different restaurant-websites for university. I'm at a point where I can parse my DB-output into a XML and send this XML to my Output-page. Now I want to change it into a HTML-table. My XSL is already finished and working, but I can't get it to work, when sending my XML.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/resources/transHTML.xsl"?>
<results>
<item>
<FoodID>1</FoodID>
<RestID>1</RestID>
...
</item>
</results>
```

I'm using Maven and my structure looks like this:

```
Project-|
        |-src-main-java-|-main-crawler-java-classes
        |               |-resources-transHTML.xsl
        |
        |-web|-WEB-INF-web.xml
        |    |-index.html (my page)
        |
        |-pom.xml
```

That's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>randoheld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>crawl</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>crawl</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>randoheld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Im using

```
Response response = Response.status(200).type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).entity(output).build();
```

to get my response, returning it right after. At the moment, I'm getting the XML-Node-Values (so XML without transformation). I guess, the problem is my path to the xsl, I already faced this with my CSS, coding it into my index.jsp after not beeing able to solve it.

Maybe someone can help me, thank's in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is  my transformation of the ResultSet:

```
public static String convertToXML(ResultSet rs) {
        StringBuffer xmlArray = null;
        try {
            xmlArray = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                    "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/transHTML.xsl\"?>\n<results>\n");
            int total_rows = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
                xmlArray.append("<col>" + rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i+1) + "</col>\n");
            }
            while (rs.next()) {
                xmlArray.append("<item>\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
                    xmlArray.append("<" + rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                             + ">" + rs.getObject(i + 1) + "</" + rs.getMetaData()
                            .getColumnLabel(i + 1) + ">\n");
            }
                xmlArray.append("</item>\n");
            }
            xmlArray.append("</results>");
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }return xmlArray.toString();
    }
```

I also switched my xsl to web-resources-transHTML.xsl.
My POM has the following code, I found in the forum:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>

                     <archive>
                       <manifest>
                          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                          <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                       </manifest>
                    </archive>

                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->

<directory>${project.basedir}/web/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>

                    <warName>mywar</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**EDIT 2:** I noticed, that my transformation returns a string, which shouldn't be a real XML right? So I turned that String into a Document:

```
 public static Document xmlToDoc(String xml) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document xmlDoc = null;
    try
    {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        xmlDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml) ) );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

before transforming it with my .xsl:

```
public static Document transformXML(Document xmlDoc){

    Document resultDoc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xslt = db.parse("resources/transHTML.xsl");

        Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(xmlDoc);
        Source xsltSource = new DOMSource(xslt);
        DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

        TransformerFactory transFact
                = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);

        trans.transform(xmlSource, result);

        resultDoc = (Document) result;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultDoc;
}
```

and finally putting it back into an output-string (because a HTML-text should be compiled right?):

```
public static String BackToString(Document xmlDoc) {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        // below code to remove XML declaration
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xmlDoc), new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
        return output;
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However it's returning an empty string. If I remove the code, deleting the XML-declaration, the declaration is beeing send, so I guess, the transformation isn't working (because there shouldn't be a declaration left right?).

Comment: Please share the transformation code written in Java. Also have you checked whether the XSL is available at the classpath when it is loaded for transformation.

Comment: Added my ResultSet-transformation and some stuff from my POM.xml. Inserting directly into my .jsp doesnt work. I should add, that I'm loading the table in a content-div with jquery, so I don't have to reload the whole page all the time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to fix it with my last three edits (converting string to document-->parse document-->convert document back to string). I had to enter the complete path to

```
Document xslt = db.parse("pathToXsl");
```

So the error really was the XML-transformation.

However I'm not really happy with it, because in a real-world-scenario, everyone would be able to see my system-path. I used the following code to check, which document was empty:

```
 public static void printDocument(Document doc, OutputStream out){
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    try {

        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));

    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Just in case, future readers want to find their error. (Sorry I wasn't able to find the link to it)